# Maximum stack depth reached: 1001 inner class

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class, limitexception

I'm trying to export record on into a tab separated text file. In getting Maximum stack depth reached: 1001 in the inner class where i'm doing the piece of code and I have pasted full code in the bottom.

```
public void addValue(Date value){
    if(value!=null){
        this.addValue(DateTime.newInstance(value.year(), value.month(), value.day()).format('dd/MM/yyyy'));    
    } else{
        this.addValue(value);
    }

}
```

Following is full code

```
public class CarerCardExportController {
    public static List<Card_Request__c> cards {get; set;}
    public static String header {get; set;}
    public static final String filename = DateTime.now().format('yyyyMMdd') +  'Carer Card Export.txt';
    public static String content {get; private set;}

    public CarerCardExportController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

    }

    public CarerCardExportController(){

    }

    public void export(){
        header = 'CarerCardNumber\tCardExpiryDate\tFirstname\tSurname\tAddress1\tAddress2\tSuburb\tState\tPostcode\tPostalAddress1\t'
                  +'PostalAddress2\tPostalSuburb\tPostalSate\tPostalPostcode\tCentrelinkCRN\tDOB\tEmail\tPackType';
        //this is all we need for the page
        cards = [SELECT Id, Carers_Card_Number__c, SC_Contact__r.FirstName, SC_Contact__r.Lastname, SC_Contact__r.MailingStreet,
                SC_Contact__r.MailingCity, SC_Contact__r.MailingPostalCode, SC_Contact__r.MailingState, SC_Contact__r.MailingCountry, 
                SC_Contact__r.OtherStreet, SC_Contact__r.OtherCity, SC_Contact__r.OtherPostalCode, SC_Contact__r.OtherState, 
                SC_Contact__r.OtherCountry, CC_Expiry_Date__c, SC_Contact__r.CRN_Number__c, SC_Contact__r.Birthdate, SC_Contact__r.Email, 
                Carer_Card_Print_Type__c FROM Card_Request__c WHERE Card_Status__c = 'Issued' AND Carer_Sub_Status__c = 'Print Request Pending' AND Card_Type__c = 'Carer Card' FOR UPDATE];

        //now process the cards
        postProcessCards();   
    }



    public class CarerRow{

        public String row;
        public Boolean firstCall;

        public CarerRow(){
            row = '';
            firstCall = false;
        }

        public CarerRow(String value){
            this();
            row = (value == null) ? '' : value;
            firstCall = true;
        }

        public void addValue(String value){
            if(!firstCall && String.isBlank(row)){
                row =(value == null) ? '' : value;
                firstCall = true;
            }
            else row += '\t' + ((value == null) ? '' : value);
        }

        public void addValue(Date value){
            if(value!=null){
                this.addValue(DateTime.newInstance(value.year(), value.month(), value.day()).format('dd/MM/yyyy'));    
            } else{
                this.addValue(value);
            }

        }
    }

    public class CarerDocument{

        private String value;

        public CarerDocument(){
            value = '';
        }

        public CarerDocument(CarerRow row){
            this();
            value = row.row;
        }

        public void addRow(CarerRow row){
            value += '\r\n' + row.row;
        }

        public Blob getBlob(){
            return Blob.valueOf(value);
        }

        public String getValue(){
            return value;
        }

    }

    public static void postProcessCards(){
        List<Card_Request__c> cardsToUpdate = new List<Card_Request__c>();
        Set<Id> updatedCardIds = new Set<Id>();

        CarerRow headers = new CarerRow(header);
        CarerDocument carerExport = new CarerDocument(headers);

        for(Card_Request__c card : cards){

            //we don't want to mutate what's displayed on the page so handling the update for cards in a separate list
            cardsToUpdate.add(new Card_Request__c(
                Id = card.Id,
                Carer_Sub_Status__c = 'Waiting - Print Receipt',
                Date_Exported__c = Date.today()
            ));

            //also we are going to link the file generated to all the cards
            updatedCardIds.add(card.Id);

            String mailingKey = card.SC_Contact__r.MailingStreet + card.SC_Contact__r.MailingCity + card.SC_Contact__r.MailingState + card.SC_Contact__r.MailingPostalCode;
            String otherKey = card.SC_Contact__r.OtherStreet + card.SC_Contact__r.OtherCity + card.SC_Contact__r.OtherState + card.SC_Contact__r.OtherPostalCode;

            CarerRow newRow = new CarerRow();
            newRow.addValue(card.Carers_Card_Number__c);
            newRow.addValue(card.CC_Expiry_Date__c);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.FirstName);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.Lastname);
            //newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.Name);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.MailingStreet);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.MailingCity);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.MailingState);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.MailingPostalCode);
            if(otherKey == mailingKey){
                newRow.addValue('');
                newRow.addValue('');
                newRow.addValue('');
                newRow.addValue('');
            }
            else{
                newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.OtherStreet);
                newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.OtherCity);
                newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.OtherState);
                newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.OtherPostalCode);                
            }
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.CRN_Number__c);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.Birthdate);
            newRow.addValue(card.SC_Contact__r.Email);
            newRow.addValue(card.Carer_Card_Print_Type__c);
            carerExport.addRow(newRow);
        }


        //create the file
        content = carerExport.getValue();
        Blob exportBlob = carerExport.getBlob(); //convert the page generated to a Blob
        ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
        conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S specify this document is in SF
        conVer.PathOnClient = filename; 
        conVer.Title = filename; 
        conVer.VersionData = exportBlob; 
        insert conVer;

        //need to fetch the content document Id
        Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;

        //link the file to all the card records
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdlsToInsert = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        for(Id cardId : updatedCardIds){
            ContentDocumentLink cDe = new ContentDocumentLink();
            cDe.ContentDocumentId = conDoc;
            cDe.LinkedEntityId = cardId;
            cDe.ShareType = 'I'; // Inferred permission, checkout description of ContentDocumentLink object for more details
            //cDe.Visibility = 'SharedUsers';
            cdlsToInsert.add(cDe);
        }
        insert cdlsToInsert;

        update cardsToUpdate;
    }

    public String getFilename(){
        return filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `CarerRow#addValue(Date)`, if `value` is `null`, then it tries to call `CarerRow#addValue(Date)` again, in which `value` will be `null`, which tries to call `CarerRow#addValue(Date)`, *ad nauseam*, until the stack limit is reached. You probably meant to write this instead:

```
    public void addValue(Date value){
        if(value!=null){
            this.addValue(DateTime.newInstance(value.year(), value.month(), value.day()).format('dd/MM/yyyy'));    
        } else{
            this.addValue((String)null);
        }
    }
```

This will call your `CarerRow#addValue(String)` instead, which should fix your problem.